# Store annotations in MapKit when user quit application

Tags: iphone, mapkit, store, mkannotation, autosave

I want my annotation to be stored when I quit the application and pop up again when I launch the application.... How can I make this possible? Any ideas?

```
-(IBAction)storeLocation:(id)sender{

    SparaPosition *position=[[SparaPosition alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    [mapView addAnnotation:position];
    savedPosition = location;
```

Please... need some help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save just one annotation's coordinates, simplest way is to use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

To save:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setDouble:location.latitude forKey:@"savedCoordinate-latitude"];
[ud setDouble:location.longitude forKey:@"savedCoordinate-longitude"];
[ud setBool:YES forKey:@"savedCoordinate-exists"];
[ud synchronize];
```

To load (in viewDidLoad for example):

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([ud boolForKey:@"savedCoordinate-exists"])
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D savedCoordinate;
    savedCoordinate.latitude = [ud doubleForKey:@"savedCoordinate-latitude"];
    savedCoordinate.longitude = [ud doubleForKey:@"savedCoordinate-longitude"];
    //create annotation object using savedCoordinate and add to map view...
}
```

Comment: The same way you are creating it in `storeLocation` except use `savedCoordinate` instead of `location`.

Comment: thanks. If I already have an annotation at start up - then how do I disable the "doMapCentering" as you said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473958/adding-and-sending-coordinates-from-application-to-maps-app   ???

Comment: Set doMapCentering to NO before you add the annotation on startup (inside the `if` in the example).

Comment: Also inside the `if`, after adding the annotation to the map, call setRegion on the map view with the center set to savedCoordinate.

Comment: and also... how do I revert the saving (removing the saved coordinates?

Comment: Use removeObjectForKey: method of NSUserDefaults or you could set the "exists" key to NO.  See the docs or sample apps for NSUserDefaults.

Comment: thanks! solved it with [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"savedCoordinate-exists"]; in the removeAnnotations IBAction.